App does not open from Widgets intermittently
We've noticed a weird bug in our app where app sometimes doesn't correctly handle being opened from the Widgets. After some debugging it looks like the issue is that the SceneDelegate functions are not called so we can't respond to the incoming URL in any way.
In general we use func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) { to handle taps from Widgets. When the issue occurs it looks like lifecycle methods are called correctly:

sceneWillEnterForeground
sceneDidBecomeActive

Related radar: FB15380995
